# Can I deconstruct a hash in block parameters in Ruby 3.1, like `|foo:|`?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby 2.7, I can effectively deconstruct a hash in block parameters:

```
>> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.7.6"
>> [{foo: 123}].each { |foo:| p foo }
123
=> [{:foo=>123}]
```

In Ruby 3.1, I can't:

```
>> RUBY_VERSION
=> "3.1.2"
>> [{foo: 123}].each { |foo:| p foo }
(irb):7:in `block in <top (required)>': missing keyword: :foo (ArgumentError)
```

It *is* possible to pattern match it *outside* the parameter list:

```
[{foo: 123}].each { |x| x => {foo:}; p foo }
```

But I'm after something *in the parameter list*, if possible.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: no

`each` just passes the `{foo: 123}` hash as the block argument, but Ruby 3 expects an actual `foo:` keyword to be passed. It's equivalent to:

```
def m(foo:)
  p foo
end

m({foo: 123})
# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0; required keyword: foo)
```

You have to either pass keyword arguments or convert the hash via `**`:

```
m(foo: 123)
# 123

m(**{foo: 123})
# 123
```

In either way, this has to be "fixed" on the caller's side.

In your code, the caller is `each`. To get your code working, you *could* define your own `each` variant which does the required conversion:

```
module Enumerable
  def each_keyword
    each { |hash| yield **hash }
  end
end
```

Which works as expected for the example data:

```
[{foo: 123}].each_keyword { |foo:| p foo }
# 123
```

However, I would just stick to `each` and fetch the value from the passed hash:

```
[{foo: 123}].each { |h| p h[:foo] }
# 123
```

If you have a hash, you should probably treat is as one.

Answer (score 3):

Difference in keyword argument handling:

```rb
# 2.7
>> [{foo: 123}].each {|*args, **kwargs| puts "args=#{args}, kwargs=#{kwargs}" }
args=[], kwargs={:foo=>123}

# 3.1
>> [{foo: 123}].each {|*args, **kwargs| puts "args=#{args}, kwargs=#{kwargs}" }
args=[{:foo=>123}], kwargs={}
# NOTE: no kwargs, no match.
```

Closest I could get:

```rb
>> [{foo: 1},{foo: 2}].each { _1 => foo:; p foo }
1
2

# in the parameter list
>> [{foo: 1},{foo: 2}].each { |i, foo: i[:foo]| p foo }
1
2
```

Comment: The `_1` + pattern matching version is clever  Not strictly in the argument list, but a similar level of convenience.

Answer (score -4):

in ruby 3 we can deconstruct using the rightward assignment like so :

```rb
[{foo: 123}, {foo: 222}].each {|h| h=> {foo:}; p foo}
123
222                                                 
 => [{:foo=>123}, {:foo=>222}]
```

note: `foo` will assign new value each iteration